# Symbol of inexact partial

Tags: math-mode, symbols

I need a symbol in Latex that I can represent the inexact partial. I need the partial with a bar in the partial.

Answer (score 5):

The bar is character octal 26; some playing with kerns does the job: the width of the bar is 9mu, so at the end there's no advance when the `\partial` symbol is typeset.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\ipartial}{{\mkern4.5mu\mathchar'26\mkern-13.5mu\partial}}

\begin{document}

$x\ipartial f$

$x\partial f$

\end{document}
```

[image]

A less efficient definition if you need to use the symbol also at smaller sizes (`\scriptstyle` or `\scriptscriptstyle`):

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\ipartial}{%
  {\mathchoice
   {\mkern4.5mu\mathchar'26\mkern-13.5mu\partial}
   {\mkern4.5mu\mathchar'26\mkern-13.5mu\partial}
   {\mkern4mu\mathchar'26\mkern-13mu\partial}
   {\mkern3.25mu\mathchar'26\mkern-12.25mu\partial}
  }%
}

\begin{document}

$x\ipartial f$

$x\partial f$

$\scriptstyle\ipartial\scriptscriptstyle\ipartial$

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you don't plan to use the symbol in `\scriptscriptstyle`, you can use

```
\newcommand{\ipartial}{{%
  \mkern4mu\nonscript\mkern0.5mu
  \mathchar'26
  \mkern-13mu\nonscript\mkern-0.5mu
  \partial
}}
```

that's as efficient as the simple version at the top, and provides the same kerning as the second (less efficient) version in `\displaystyle`, `\textstyle` and `\scriptstyle`.

Answer (score 2):

This should yield the same spacing as `\partial` and supports the smaller math sizes.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine,scalerel}
\def\mpartial{\ThisStyle{\stackinset{r}{-.4\LMex}{c}{-.2\LMex}{%
  $\SavedStyle\mathchar'26$}{$\SavedStyle\partial$}}}
\begin{document}
\[
x \partial f
\]
\[
x \mpartial f
\]
\[
\scriptstyle x \mpartial f
\]
\[
\scriptscriptstyle x \mpartial f
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]